# How can we get the original event in ember controller action

Tags: ember.js

How can we get the original event in ember action while handling action inside controller?

**Controller**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Controller.extend({
    showDetails:function(id)
    {
       // I want like $(this).position().top
    }
});
```

Template

```
{{#each item in list}}
   <em {{action "showDetails" item.id bubbles=false}}></em>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{#each item in list}}
   <em onclick={{action "showDetails" item.id}}></em>
{{/each}}
```

In controller,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        showDetails(id, event) {
            //i want like $(this).position().top
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: console.log(event) // result undefined

Comment: have a look at this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/2dde08974078c53c9a19ad8ead56dca8?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)

Comment: what is `<em` ? is it html element  or ember curly component ?

Comment: it is just html tag

Comment: ok . updated [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/2dde08974078c53c9a19ad8ead56dca8?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) using em element ..if it does not work out show us the exact code ?